# Finding and DI defining a concrete org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient

Tags: java, spring, java-8, java-11

How do I register a CONCRETE implementation of the below interface (via applicationcontext.xml) (xml configuration)?

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient
```

"Specified class is an interface"

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html

```
public interface WebClient
```

Full code

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class MyClientProxy implements IMyClientProxy {

    private final WebClient webClient;

    private static Logger LOGGER;


    public MyClientProxy(Logger lgr, WebClient webClient) {
        if (null == lgr) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Logger is null");
        }
        this.LOGGER = lgr;

        if (null == webClient) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("WebClient is null");
        }
        this.webClient = webClient;
    }
}
```

imports

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-webflux
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-webflux', version: '2.3.1.RELEASE'
```

Obviously, this is not working

(from applicationcontext.xml)

```
    <bean id="zzzWebClientBean"
          class="org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient">
    </bean>
```

But in the "what I tried" category....

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was a factory static method.

```
    <bean id="zzzWebClientBean"
          class="org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient" factory-method="create">
    </bean>
```